# how do i choose randomly items from two different lists and display them together?

Tags: python, list, random

I want to generate new animals composed from elements from list1 and list2, e.g.: Sea-rat, Fire-horse, Nile-cat
The mix should be generated randomly.
Can someone point out, what Im doing wrong and why?

```
def new_animal():
    list1 = [ "Nile", "Sea", "Land", "Fire" ]
    list2 = [ "-rat", "-lion", "-cat", "-horse" ]
    list1 + list2
    return new_animal()
        
    import random
    random.choice(list1) + (list2)

    return new_animal()
    
def Zoo():
    new_animal = animal()
    print = "What animal is this?"
    answer = "That animal is a" + new_animal
    print(answer)
```

I believe i do something wrong with the part where i add lists, but i need only one element of each list...
otherwise i believe my information flow is correct?

Comment: Why do you think that you are doing something wrong?

Comment: For one I am very glad, that i made the defZoo() more or less correct. But since I learn on my own I have to understand the orthographics so to speak like where is a paranthesis and why, where is a "" or a : ...and so on 
aswell as understanding the structure, the logic. But I am incredibly happy for all the answers!!

Answer (score 1):

Call `random.choice()` separately on each list, then concatenate them.

```
def new_animal():
    list1 = [ "Nile", "Sea", "Land", "Fire" ]
    list2 = [ "-rat", "-lion", "-cat", "-horse" ]

    return random.choice(list1) + random.choice(list2)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are a few issues with your code. Let's break them down and provide a corrected version.

You're not properly concatenating the elements from the two lists. You should use the + operator to concatenate them, but you need to do it when generating the new animal name.

You're missing the correct way to import the random module.

You're redefining the new_animal function inside itself, which leads to infinite recursion.

use this:

```
import random

def new_animal():
    list1 = ["Nile", "Sea", "Land", "Fire"]
    list2 = ["-rat", "-lion", "-cat", "-horse"]
    
    element1 = random.choice(list1)
    element2 = random.choice(list2)
    
    new_animal_name = element1 + element2
    
    return new_animal_name

def Zoo():
    animal_name = new_animal()
    print("What animal is this?")
    answer = "That animal is a " + animal_name
    print(answer)

Zoo()
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining why it did not worked out with defining my function. Also now I have two versions of how I can call a random element, so this has been helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can consolidate the creation of composed animal names into a single return value.
In the line random.choice(list1) + (list2), you should use random.choice(list2) to randomly select an element from list2.

```
import random

def new_animal():
    list1 = [ "Nile", "Sea", "Land", "Fire" ]
    list2 = [ "-rat", "-lion", "-cat", "-horse" ]
    return random.choice(list1) + random.choice(list2)

def Zoo():
    new_animal_name = new_animal()
    print("What animal is this?")
    answer = "That animal is a " + new_animal_name
    print(answer)

Zoo()
```

Comment: I opted for putting the randomization into one singel return value, thank you!

Answer (score -2):

Defining a lambda function called 'new_animal,' which takes no arguments and is used to create a new animal name.

```
import random;
new_animal = lambda: random.choice(["Nile", "Sea", "Land", "Fire"]) + random.choice(["-rat", "-lion", "-cat", "-horse"])
```

Comment: I am not familiar with lambda yet, but I am going to check it out further, thank you!